# Unexpected behaviour using sapply on a factor in R

Tags: r, sapply

Using R, I recently got surprised by the output of sapply when used on a factor. Have a look at the following:

```
> F <- as.factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))

> sapply(F, function(x) x)
[1] A B C D E F
Levels: A B C D E F

> sapply(F, function(x) (x=="C"))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

So far so good, both outputs are as expected. But now, it is getting strange:

```
> sapply(F, function(x) if (TRUE) x else NA)
[1] A B C D E F
Levels: A B C D E F

> sapply(F, function(x) if (x=="C") x else NA)
[1] NA NA  3 NA NA NA

> sapply(F, function(x) {if (x=="C") foo <- "bar"; x})
[1] A B C D E F
Levels: A B C D E F
```

In these three cases, the first and the last results are as I would expect. The second one is somehow strange: I would expect to get something like `[1] NA NA "C" NA NA NA`.

My first guess was that the comparison `(x=="C")` has some impact on the `x` value inside of the if-clause. (Not outside of the clause otherwise we would have another result in the last case above.) Probably the `x` is treated as its index inside of the clause.

However this guess is not compatible with the following two observations:

```
> sapply(F, function(x) if (x==x) x else NA)
[1] A B C D E F
Levels: A B C D E F

> sapply(F, function(x) if (x=="C") F[x] else NA)
[1] NA NA  3 NA NA NA
```

Here, the `(x==x)` doesn't seem to have any influence at all and if `x` would be its index inside of the clause, we would get back a `"C"` instead of a `3`.

My actual questions is: why does this happen? 
(By now I'm quite sure this is some factor related feature I'm not aware of...)

Comment: That's just because of the simplification done by `sapply` as far as I can tell. Try `lapply` for comparison. Or convert `F` to character first.

Comment: `sapply` is just `lapply` with the difference that it calls `simplify2array` to the result of `lapply`. Try your lines with `lapply` instead. Then, see what `simplify2array` does. It calls `unlist`. What happens when you `unlist` a `list` in which each element is a `factor` with the same levels? And what happens if that condition is not met?

Comment: @nicola Regarding your second to last sentence: It's not necessary that they have the same levels. See `help("unlist")`.

Comment: @dotton You are mixing a logical `NA` value with factor values. The common mode is integer, which is what you get. Put a factor `NA` into your `else` to get a factor.

Comment: @nicola You are right, lapply works as expected and the "strange"  transformation is done by the simplify2array method.

Comment: @Roland After putting a `NA` factor into my `else` I truely get the expected factor, thx! I was not aware that the `NA` can have different "forms"...

Comment: somebody (maybe OP) please distill these comments into an answer?

Comment: @dotton See `help("NA")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sapply` is basically `lapply` followed by `simplify2array` which is in this case simply a call to `unlist`.

First let's check if the behavior is caused by `lapply`:

```
lapply(F, function(x) if (x=="C") x else NA)
#[[1]]
#[1] NA
#
#[[2]]
#[1] NA
#
#[[3]]
#[1] C
#Levels: A B C D E F
#
#[[4]]
#[1] NA
#
#[[5]]
#[1] NA
#
#[[6]]
#[1] NA
```

As you see, the the third element is still a factor. However, the `NA` values are of class "logical":

```
class(lapply(F, function(x) if (x=="C") x else NA)[[1]])
#[1] "logical"
```

This means two quotes from `help("unlist")` are relevant:

> Factors are treated specially. If all non-list elements of x are
>   factors (or ordered factors) then the result will be a factor with
>   levels the union of the level sets of the elements, in the order the
>   levels occur in the level sets of the elements (which means that if
>   all the elements have the same level set, that is the level set of the
>   result).

and

> Where possible the list elements are coerced to a common mode during
>   the unlisting, and so the result often ends up as a character vector.
>   Vectors will be coerced to the highest type of the components in the
>   hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex <
>   character < list < expression: pairlists are treated as lists.

The second quote describes what happens here; the common mode of a factor (which internally is an integer vector with attributes) and a logical value is an integer. And this is what you get.

If you want to make sure that you get a factor vector from `sapply` create a factor `NA` value in your `else` condition:

```
sapply(F, function(x) if (x=="C") x else {is.na(x) <- TRUE; x})
#[1] <NA> <NA> C    <NA> <NA> <NA>
#Levels: A B C D E F
```